# Execute multiple JQuery functions not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-select2

I made an automatic click to add a new line. in it there are select2 and datepicker. I refresh this after the new line. but they cannot be executed at the same time.

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
                var i = 1;
                $("#add_row").click(function () {
                    $('tr').find('input').prop('enable', true);
                    $('#addr' + i).html("<td><input type='text' name='nama[]" + i +
                        "' placeholder='Nama Kegiatan' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input data-date-format='dd/mm/yyyy' data-date-viewmode='years' type='text' placeholder='Pilih Tanggal Berkas' name='waktu[]" + i +
                        "' class='datepicker'></td><td><select class='js-example-basic-single' style='width:200px;' name='idunsur[]" + i +
                        "' > <?php foreach ($unsur as $u) { echo '<option value=' . $u->id_unsur . ' >' . $u->unsur_nama . '</option>'; } ?></select></td><td><input type='file' accept='.pdf' name='file[]" + i +
                        "' placeholder='File kegiatan' class='form-control input-md'/></td>");

                    $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
                   i++;
                   $('.datepicker').datepicker().refresh();
                    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2().refresh();
                });

            });
```

[image: output]

Comment: Are the two plugins compatible with each other and your HTML? It might help to provide a [functional example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Also, does each one have a `refresh()` function? I think `datepicker` has a [refresh method](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-refresh), but I'm not sure about `select2`.

Comment: @showdev oke it just my mistake, i delete these refresh functions, it works

Answer (score 0):

Delete the refresh funtion, because the function does not exist, if you want to refresh, simply make initialization. like this:

```
$('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```